# does spring has a way to inject properties file to bean without xml?

Tags: spring

I' m writing a project currently using spring' s javaconfig without spring xml files. And now I' m facing a problem.

I have a properties config file and I want to make it a spring's `@Component`, but I can't find a nice way to inject the properties to the bean's field just like in the `@Configuration` with `@PropertySource`. It uses `@Value` or `@Inject` Environment to get the properties.

and now my bean is not @Configuration and I don't want to make it with `@Bean` in the `@Configuration` class. I want it auto-scaned by spring.

does somebody has some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the Java configuration

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(name = "props", value = { "classpath:myProps.properties" })
public class AppConfig {
```

In some Spring bean

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("props")
private Properties myProperties;//+setter
```